# children not being added from custom jsx element

Tags: html, typescript, nested, jsx

I have this custom Jsx component like so:

```
const Button = ({title}) => {
   return <div className={title}></div>;
}
```

I use it like so:

```
<Button title={"ll"}>
    <h1>Some extra custom text</h1>
    <span>span text of button</span>
</Button>
```

The output is the following:

```html
<div class="ll"></div>
```

But it should be:

```html
<div class="ll">
    <h1>Some extra custom text</h1>
    <span>span text of button</span>
</div>
```

Why is it not adding the children?

**Edit**
I am using a custom jsx factory. I am not using react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
const Button = ({title, children}) => {
   return <div className={title}>{children}</div>;
}
```

Edit1: Try this:

```
const h1 = <h1>Some extra custom text</h1>;
const span = <span>span text of button</span>;

<Button title={"ll"} h1={h1} span={span}></Button>

const Button = ({title, h1, span}) => {
   return <div className={title}>{h1}{span}</div>;
}
```

Edit2: Try this:

```
const Button = (props) => {
    return <div className={props.title}>{props.children}</div>;
}

<Button title={"ll"}>
  <h1>Some extra custom text</h1>
  <span>span text of button</span>
</Button>
```

Comment: I tried this already :) but  it give me an error on the line where i use the button as jsx since one argument is missing. `<Button title={ll}>` that is the line i am talking about. 
This is the full error: `Property 'children' is missing in type '{ title: string; }' but required in type '{ title: any; children: any; }'`

Comment: Are you using typeScript?

Comment: I updated another thing to try in my original answer

Comment: it says: `JSX fragment is not supported when using --jsxFactory`
I fixed it by replacing the empty tag with div. But this feels like it defeats the purpose of jsx, no?

Comment: I added one more thing you could do, instead of destructuring props, just pass it directly as an object. It's definitely something with the typeScript; if that doesn't work, try Edit 1 but use a span tag instead of fragments.

Comment: I am not using react, i am using a custom jsx factory, probably should have mentioned it.. :)

Comment: Try my second edit where you don't destructure props; it's definitely an issue with typescript not liking how JSX can pass children without assigning them to an attribute.

Comment: Yeah that kinda does something, something else now gives me an error. I will look into that, if i fix that error and it still works I will most certainly accept your answer :) But its late for me so I will look at tomorrow! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Ok np; I also re edited Edit1. Instead of wrapping in a div, you can break up the children into 2 props.